# What's this concept called?

Tags: java, syntax, android-volley

We have this method to make a request using the Volley library:

```
public void requestWithSomeHttpHeaders() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://www.somewebsite.com";
    StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // response
                Log.d("Response", response);
            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
            }
        }
    ) {     
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                params.put("User-Agent", "Nintendo Gameboy");  
                params.put("Accept-Language", "fr");

                return params;  
        }
    };
    queue.add(getRequest);

}
```

Notice the part:

```
{     
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                params.put("User-Agent", "Nintendo Gameboy");  
                params.put("Accept-Language", "fr");

                return params;  
        }
    };
```

It confuses me because there's no comma before it, so it's not a function argument. If you look at the method definition:

```
public StringRequest(
            int method,
            String url,
            Listener<String> listener,
            @Nullable ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

there's no clear code which explains support for this.

What's this concept called and how do you write code that supports this?

Comment: This is called an anonymous class.

Comment: A new anonymous subclass of `StringRequest` is created with two arguments (an anonymous subclass of `Response.Listener` and an anonymous subclass of `Response.ErrorListener`). The created anonymous subclass of `StringRequest` itself overrides the method `StringRequest.getHeaders()`.

Comment: @SLaks Okay that concept I know, but how does `StringRequest()` know how to handle that class if it's not passed as a method argument?

Comment: The construct would be much clearer if both subclasses of `Listener` and `ErrorListener` were passed as a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet shows the creation of an instance of an anonymous class that extends `StringRequest` and overrides the `getHeaders()` method.